# Can I disable specific iOS features with my app?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to prevent use of iOS features with my app? For example, preventing use of the camera or prohibiting phone calls or texts during academic class hours.

Comment: Is jailbreaking an option for you?

Comment: In general, Apple makes it hard to control or even access facilities that are not intended for app use, and is apt to reject any app that attempts to perform such access/control.  This is for valid data privacy reasons (plus, of course, it gives them monopoly control over these facilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the devices are yours, you can enable Guided Access. Then you can prevent the user from leaving the app or doing anything else with it. But if the devices are somebody else's, there's no way for you to put these kinds of restrictions on them from an app.

Apps run inside of a sandbox, where they can only access certain information, and can only do certain things that Apple specifically allows them to do. You can't, for example, prevent normal phone functionality thru your app. You also can't access certain things such as contacts without the user granting permission first, because apps might have legitimate reasons for doing so but shouldn't just be allowed this without the user's consent.

There's really no way to accomplish what you want short of being the supplier of the devices during class. And students could still use their own devices to text and such if they wanted anyway.

Comment: Is freezing the UI like text panel possible option for the app?

Answer (score 1):

Not without jailbreaking. But you can enable Kiosk Mode that doesn't allow leaving a certain app without a password:

`Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Guided Access`

Answer (score 0):

No.

iOS does not allow an app to alter any system functionality.